# Why isn't my JQuery get() funtion working for JSON urls but is working for non-JSON urls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, get

I have two files in the same folder as my HTML file and main Javascript file:

```
hello.js
hello.json
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="page.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my main Javascript (i.e., not the hello.js file):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("hello.js", function(response) {
    console.log("Hello")
    });
});
```

As you can see, this is some pretty complex code.  The Javascript, as it appears above, works fine to print out "Hello" on the console.  When I change "hello.js" to "hello.json", nothing is printed.  I tried this with a few different JSON files and nothing worked.

I don't think it should matters since the data isn't actually being parsed, but I did validate that the JSON data in hello.json is correctly formatted.

Comment: maybe your server doesn't serve json files? can you give us a url to test this with?

Comment: Have you checked the network panel in the developer tools on whatever browser you are using? (Should be able to open it using F12 in most mainstream browsers). This should tell you if request is being made, and if so what response is being returned by the server. That would help narrow things down.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()` to retrieve JSON files or try specifying the dataType as JSON when you are retrieving JSON file using `$.get()`. That could work.

Comment: Shouldn't matter at all, `$.getJSON` is just a shortcut for `$.get` with the datatype set to JSON.